# Dim instruments and messages, too dark to see

Tags: electrical, lights, dashboard

So this is problem I am having on two vehicles. First found it on my Silverado for temp/climate panel. the lights are too dim to see, they don't get any brighter when adjusting dimmer. Second vehicle is Volvo. All panels are dim, and dimmer does not do anything. This vehicle all dash lights and messages and radio is dim and not readable (luckily speed and fuel gages are manual). I think two vehicles might have different issues. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a new phenomenon? Have you tested the batteries and charging systems?

Comment: in the past both vehicles had batteries replaced.

Comment: Yes, but how long ago, and more importantly how are they now?

Comment: in truck 6 months ago, in volvo last week, no difference, seems battery unrelated. both batteries were changed for unrelated to dash lights reason

Comment: If the dimmer doesn't do anything, there is a chance that the dimmer has failed.